# VLC-Qt building from source on Windows error

Tags: c++, qt, build, cmake, vlc-qt

The point is that I try to build [vlc-qt](https://github.com/vlc-qt/vlc-qt/releases) binding from source. I do the following:

1. Get libvlc-qt_0.10.0_win32_msvc2013.7z sources
2. Open my Qt5 Creator (from MVSC2013 version)
3. Open /src/CMakeLists.txt with it
4. Run CMake
5. Press build

Should work, but instead I get the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\sdk\include\vlc\plugins\vlc_threads.h:403: ошибка: C3861: 'poll': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\sdk\include\vlc\plugins\vlc_configuration.h:103: ошибка: C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'config_GetIntChoices'
C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\sdk\include\vlc\plugins\vlc_configuration.h:103: ошибка: C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\sdk\include\vlc\plugins\vlc_configuration.h:104: ошибка: C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\sdk\include\vlc\plugins\vlc_configuration.h:105: ошибка: C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'config_GetPszChoices'
C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\sdk\include\vlc\plugins\vlc_configuration.h:105: ошибка: C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\sdk\include\vlc\plugins\vlc_configuration.h:106: ошибка: C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

The surprises are that this project searches for some files in the current VLC player installation (Program Files is likely not the best place to get the dependecies), also that nothing's told about this behavior on the repository page, at first sight at at least.

Currently I'm trying to remove/reinstall player, run CMake with some keys etc. By the way, downloading CMake with gui never helped.

Could anyone, please, point me at the mistake in building. Thanks in advance.

---

UPD:
Thanks, krnekit, it helped to get the key! Ah, it occured to be even more complicated (msvc 2013 update 4 used).

Briefly:

- It's pretty hard to build the binding from source via Qt Creator + nmake
- Telling CMake with CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH variable, where qt required libraries are helps a lot
- The problem of searching vlc player headers in sdk is solved similarly after some of the Cmake configuring
- When I  started building my sample with the vlc-qt sources included, instead of using the shared dll, I understood that /src/windows contains headers (poll.h and other)  are requied to prevent the errors. Don't really know, why it didn't work with Cmake doing it instaed of me

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with vlc, not with vlc-qt. Your program should be compiled with at least VS 2013 Update 2 (or maybe even more recent).

Alternatively, the quick and dirty solution is to modify vlc includes, see [this bugreport](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/11327) for details. You also should provide poll.h include file.